# passing variables vs instances to constructor

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have a class named Locations, it should accept 3 parameters name, city_id, country_id.

What is the best solution for passing these values, should i pass variables or instances of their classes.

```
$location = new Locations('Dubai, UAE', 1, 2);
$location = new Locations('Dubai, UAE', $cityId, $countryId);
```

I believe for the sake of clarity and the single responsibility i should use dependency injection

```
$location = new Locations('Dubai, UAE', new City('Dubai'), new Country('UAE'));
```

When and why should i use variables (IDs) instead of instances?

Comment: More or less my opinion, but i feel like you should only ever pass objects if you are using them for some calculations or operations, not just storing them. There is probably someone with a proper answer with sources.

Comment: Thanks @KevinSijbers

Comment: The answer to this is a matter of opinion, and therefore is off-topic on stack overflow.

Comment: Why is the class named in the plural form as it represents only one location?

Comment: @worldofjr Thanks for your input, it's a best practice/design pattern problem, i believe it has everything to do with stackoverflow, otherwise you won't see people answering. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When and why should i use variables (IDs) instead of instances?

That is a question of the design of your application and it can greatly differ in which layer you are.

For example for manipulating a recordset in the database, you might just need the id value (non-zero, positive integer) to perform an operation on a specific recordset. In such a case you would need the ID.

A **Location** on the other hand might not even need the ID to operate.

As one design goal might (should) be, to do as little as necessary, I'd say you don't pass the ID-values to the **Location** constructor as it otherwise would be dependent on the whole system in which these ids are coming from (e.g. the database). That would couple the database layer and even the database itself to the **Location** class.

But the **Location** class should work without caring about the database at all. At least if so, you can make more flexible use out of it, which allows you to develop further.

This are just some generic pointers. It can be even more implementation specific like when creating something similar to what is outlined in [*Flyweight Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

So you should better ask and test your design that it does as little as necessary to do the job.

There can be performance reasons for example, it's much faster to create and pass around integer values (IDs) than to instantiate and pass around object values (objects), but not always and it can be even negligible.

Some things I'd like to clarify and comment on in context of your question and my answer:

1. Variables can be both IDs (values) or instances. Technically an object variable in PHP is just like an ID, it contains the ID (reference) of the actual object in memory.
2. You can treat a constructor as implementation detail. That done, it is easy to change it later which allows you to defer the details.
3. I named it **Location** class as it is singular. The name of the class should be representative and not mislead. **Locations** sounds like a collection of zero or more **Location** objects.
4. This question can't be fully answered as it depends on so many things. To better make up your mind also consider [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44046904/367456) which shows some more decision making points.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second.

Using OOP is working with objects. By passing objects, you can **ask** the passed object for something.

If you pass primitives like ints, it's without context. A passed object has its own data and logic, so he knows the best by itself. The int hasn't.

In your case `$cityId` is **naked data** of a `City` object: you disrespect the `City` object, because you pass a totally context-less value.

Comment: It is not totally context-less, the value on it's own would be, but by passing it as a specific method parameter, this gives context to the value. That context is not as strong as having an object, at least until it's not just a value object.

Comment: With passing as a specific method parameter you miss the validation of this value. Who should validate? By passing the instance it's a very valid manner, because that instance knows all about himself ;-) Secondly, it sounds very procedural.

Comment: Well technically I'm in the school that says you only pass valid method parameters. So to answer your question "who should validate" it is the caller. Same for instances btw nothing special for IDs, so just to answer your question. What you perhaps mean is that it's more comfortable to pass a concrete type instead of just a not-so-much-saying number, there I'm totally with you.

Comment: Ok, the caller should pass a valid instance/value. But if not, with an instance, there's a context available. With a value there isn't. Moreover, passing values sounds not as OOP. You really mis flexibility like working with interface types.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with PHP is that by assuming your parameter is a City object, you are now relying on the rest of the application to do this properly. You could check for the right types inside the constructor, but that would not be immediately obvious from the function header.

You are adding dependency one way or another. The question is which form of dependency fits best:

1. Using an integer, and building the City object in the constructor would cause a dependency with your datasource, like a database, in an entity class, which can be problematic
2. Saving the integer, and including a function getCity that takes a database object, would create this same dependency, but is more manageable, it however means that you are now passing around the database object.
3. Passing the city object means it has to either check or make assumptions about the value of the parameter, since PHP uses dynamic typing, which adds obfuscated requirements, which can be annoying unless you have good documentation.
4. Passing city and changing it in any way in Location would cause issues (some very hard to track down bugs in your future if things get complicated), which means your object should really be immutable.
5. Does your location even need a city? Is it used for any operations, or is it just used to display? In many situations I've seen, the only use of objects in actual use-cases was retrieving the id of the object passed around, which might be easier to read, but is inefficient and prone to problems if the object isn't immutable